# Using multiple different arguments with program that compares two files

Tags: c, file-io, command-line-arguments

I'm making a program that compares two text files with the console arguments `./a -i test1.txt test2.txt`, where `-i` can be either `-i`, `-w`, or `-l`. What I'm trying to do is call a specific function if there is no `-i` argument, as in `./a test1.txt test2.txt`, but I have been unable to make it work.

Here's a piece of my code showing my main and my target, cs_character:

```
int cs_character(FILE* fp1, FILE* fp2, const char arg1[], const char arg2[]) {
    int c1;
    int c2;
    int count = 0;
    while((c1 = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF && (c2 = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF) {

        if (c1 != c2){
            printf("%s %d", "files differ: char \n", count);
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    if(c1 == EOF && c2 != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s %s", "EOF on \n", arg1);
    }
    if(c2 == EOF && c1 != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s %s", "EOF on \n", arg2);
    }
    printf("%s", "files are equal\n");
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t i;
    int j = 2;
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    fp1 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    fp2 = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    for (i = 1; i < (size_t)argc && argv[i][0] == '-'; i++) {
        if (argv[i][1] == '-') {
            i++;
            break;
        }
        switch(argv[i][1]) {
        case 'l':
            printf("%s", "part l incomplete.");
            break;
        case 'w':
            word(fp1, fp2, argv[2], argv[3]);
            break;
        case 'i':
            character(fp1, fp2, argv[2], argv[3]);
            break;
        case 'c':
            cs_character(fp1, fp2, argv[2], argv[3]);
            break;
        case 'u':
            cs_word(fp1, fp2, argv[2], argv[3]);
            break;
        default:
            character(fp1, fp2, argv[2], argv[3]);
            break;      
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Secondly, what would be the best way to go about this without the specific indexes for `argv[2]` and `argv[3]`, allowing multiple arguments but still able to detect the files?

Comment: Just decide what you want your command line format to be. File names can be any arguments, for example, starting with the first one that doesn't begin with `-`. Also, why do you define `size_t i;`? Make it `int i;` and you don't need those casts. It's just an integer index. Certain C functions look for a `size_t` argument because it represents a size (for example, size of a buffer), but you don't need it for general integers. An index isn't a size.

Comment: If there is no argument there is no '-' you could check for    argv[i][1] != '-'

Comment: Make sure to check for errors after you open a file. Unless this is a programming exercise with specific guidelines, I would use the getopt() library to do the argument parsing for you.

Comment: Since you stop the loop as soon as there is no `-`, you can check if `i` is still less than `argc`. If there are exactly two items left, those are your input files; anything else would indicate a bad command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke this without an option, the `for` loop in `main()` exits
immediately because `argv[i][0] == '-'` is false. It would be better to
set a flag to whatever you want the default to be, then check the
arguments to see if the user specified something else. Something like
this:

```
char option;
option = DEFAULT_OPTION;
if (argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] != '-') {
    // change option depending on argv[1][1]
}
// call function depending on option
```